# angular-route is not working it does not throw any errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple app. When I start the app it works fine, both angular and angular-route are loaded, the config function is executed and "otherwise" works as intended.

However, both boxes and versions do not work and no HTML is injected. The main page just says

```
<!-- ngView:  -->
```

and that's it.

THERE ARE 0 ERROR MESSAGES!!! The console is just empty as a desert.

I tried everything and it should work but it doesn't. I even tried replacing the browserify calls and including angular directly in the html - no success.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>app</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="mainheader">
            <div class="client-logo"></div>
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </header>
        <nav class="mainmenu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#/boxes" id="boxes">Boxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/versions" id="versions">Versions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
    <script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

My JS:

```
'use strict';

require('angular/angular');
require('angular-route/angular-route');
var controllers = require('./controllers');

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/boxes', {
                tamplate: 'views/boxes.html',
                controller: 'boxController'
            })
            .when('/versions', {
                tamplate: 'views/versions.html',
                controller: 'versionsController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/boxes'
            });
    }
]);

app.controller('boxController', controllers.boxController);
app.controller('versionsController', controllers.versionsController);
```

Example view:

```
<h2>Boxes</h2>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Example controler:

```
'use strict';

exports.boxController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Box Controller';
    console.log('boxes');
};

exports.versionsController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Versions Controller';
    console.log('versions');
};
```

Comment: I am confused. where did you get the exports var?

Comment: Are you using batarang? Also what is tamplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm as stupid as they come, the problem is a spelling error, it's tEmplate!

Thanks for the responses.